# VSTO addon save files in ownCloud

Tags: outlook, vsto, owncloud

I'm looking for a solution to send a file as an attachment to someone's email, the file is saved to ownCloud, and the recipient only receives a link to download the attachment in the body of the email.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You just need to handle the [ItemSend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend) event of the Application class which is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program.

In the event `ItemSend` handler you may extract the attached files and start uploading them to the webserver. You may cancel the process of sending the email and initiate it anew as soon as all files are uploaded. Before calling the `Send` method on the item you should paste the links for the uploaded files.